# Non-semiconductor CW laser types for 445-465nm

Tags: laser

Am I missing something in this list of non-semiconductor CW laser types to get emission in the range of 445-465nm? Are there any crystals directly emitting in this range with UV pump?

Currently I am aware of:

1. Ti:Sapphire + doubling
2. Dye lasers - Stilbene 3, Coumarin 120&47 e.t.c
3. Argon laser - 454.6 nm, 457.9 nm and 465.8 nm
4. 914nm line of Nd:YVO4 doubled
5. Cr:LiSAF and Cr:LiCAF + doubling

Comment: Try http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html.. 3968 results

Comment: He-Cd is 442, just outside your range. Krypton is 468, just the other side. Not quite what you want though.

Comment: @CuriousOne I assume line of the atom itself and line in practical crystal is different. Also, not every line could be realized in a crystal and finally not every line is suitable for a laser... So it might be extremely hard to get to practical system from this list...

Comment: Acridine orange might work http://www.bio-rad.com/webroot/web/pdf/lsr/literature/Bulletin_2421.pdf

Comment: Don't know much about https://www.rp-photonics.com/upconversion_lasers.html . But apparently they come in blue. Usually longer wavelength than your range, but sometimes in range, e.g. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19855716

Comment: This might help you: [Blue continuously pumped upconversion lasing in Tm:YLiF4](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/apl/60/21/10.1063/1.106919)